# How to reverse animation of the Bootstrap 4 Progress bar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to reverse the animation of the Progress bar.
currently, it's going from right to left

**Expected**
I need animation from left to right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. When I run your code in the snippet it doesn't move at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this same issue by using the following CSS:

```css
.progress-bar {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add class `progress-bar-animated-reverse` to your progress bar and add the following css rule :

```
.progress-bar-animated-reverse {
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```